# Apache DRILL unsupported Decimal types error

Tags: apache-drill

there. 
I have a problem querying this maprDB json, using Apache Drill Explorer or sqline:

`{"_id":"fd7ce3c4-b9f3","latitude":{"$decimal":"51.0509827"},"longitude":{"$decimal":"-114.0162794"},"customerId":"287915990","brand":"TCO"}`

> SELECT * FROM dfs.json.geo

produce the following error message:

```
UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION ERROR: Decimal type is currently not supported
```

I can read other files with the same type without a problem. Apache Drill has the following options set:
`store.json.read_numbers_as_double=True`
`store.json.all_text_mode=False`
`planner.enable_decimal_data_type=True`

Drill is 1.8 version. Any ideas what can I do to fix that? or maybe its a bug?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find a resolution for this?